# Multi-thread. Undefined behaviour with two while loops in two different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop, mutex

```
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

int counter = 0;
mutex m;

void thread1() {
    while(1) {
        m.lock();
        cout << "th1 " << counter << endl;
        ++counter;
        if (counter == 300) {
            m.unlock();
            break;
        }
        m.unlock();
    }
}

void thread2() {
    while(1) {
        m.lock();
        cout << "th2 " << counter << endl;
        if (counter == 10) {
            counter = 300;
            m.unlock();
            break;
        }
        m.unlock();
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    thread th1(thread1);
    thread th2(thread2);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running two threads with while loops. Why despite the fact that I use `mutex` `lock` and `unlock` result of this code is different every time.
First code from function `thread1` is executed X-times, then code from function `thread2` is executed y-times.
Shouldn't them be executed one after another .. `thread1` -> `thread2` -> `thread1` -> etc ?

Comment: I understand that you have no undefined behaviour, but defined behaviour : undetermination of scheduling.

Comment: the test "if (counter == 10)" may never be become true because thread1 happily increases counter beyond 10 before thread2 gets re-scheduled.

Comment: I think your idea of how threads work is wrong. There's nothing to say that a loop of thread1 will happen and then a loop of thread2 will happen straight after and they'll keep swapping like that.

Comment: The OS schedules the timing of the threads. `thread1` could easily run through many iterations of its loop before `thread2` is scheduled to run, and vice versa. And once they are both running, the OS will swap between the threads at times of its own choosing. The `mutex` only ensures that the two threads cant access the `counter` (or `cout`) at the same time. It does nothing to control the timing of the loop iterations in relation to each other.

Comment: Obviously, if you want to strictly alternate between both threads, it would be much simpler and efficient to write a single loop (in a single thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *non-deterministic* because you have a race condition.

Every time you unlock the mutex both threads race to lock it again.

Also in your code you can increment over 10 and miss the exit condition in thread2 which is not what I think you want.

One way you could sync the execution to be what you described (thread1, thread2, thread1, etc..) is by using a condition variable (std::condition_variable).

Here is your code with some slight modification to get the sync behavior:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;
bool flag = false;
mutex m;
condition_variable c;

void thread1() {
    while(1) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
        c.wait(lk, []{ return flag; });
        cout << "th1 " << counter << endl;
        if (counter == 300) {
            flag=!flag;
            lk.unlock();
            c.notify_one();
            break;
        }
        counter++;
        flag=!flag;
        lk.unlock();
        c.notify_one();
    }
}

void thread2() {
    while(1) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lk(m);
        c.wait(lk, []{ return !flag; });
        cout << "th2 " << counter << endl;
        if (counter == 10) {
            counter = 300;
            flag=!flag;
            lk.unlock();
            c.notify_one();   
            break;
        }
        flag=!flag;
        lk.unlock();
        c.notify_one();
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    thread th1(thread1);
    thread th2(thread2);
    th1.join();
    th2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
th2 0
th1 0
th2 1
th1 1
th2 2
th1 2
th2 3
th1 3
th2 4
th1 4
th2 5
th1 5
th2 6
th1 6
th2 7
th1 7
th2 8
th1 8
th2 9
th1 9
th2 10
th1 300
```

then the program exits...

A couple of notes:

The threads are sync'd on the `bool flag` variable.

`flag` is used to create the predicate used in the wait methods called on the conditional_variable

```
c.wait(lk, []{ return flag; });
```

which is just a lambda which returns the flag current value.

th1 triggers on `flag==true` and th2 on `flag==false`.

The `notify_one` method tells the waiting thread to check its condition.

And we use a `unique_lock` instance specifically because we need to be able to manually lock/unlock the lock based on the condition.

Comment: I don't think it's *undefined* behavior so much as *non-deterministic* behavior, which is common and usually expected when doing multithreaded programming.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner. What would make this undefined? If he had the same code but without a mutex blocking access to the `counter` variable?

Comment: @Fermi-r yes, that would do it... in C++ language-lawyer lingo, "undefined behavior" has a specific meaning along the lines of "the language spec said you shouldn't do that, and you did it anyway, so your program is buggy and therefore no matter what it does or doesn't do it's your fault and we wash our hands of it".   There are a lot of errors that invoke undefined behavior, but simply having two threads both trying to acquire the same mutex at the same time isn't one of them (because while it's not predictable which will get the lock first, it's still legal/well-defined C++ code)